# forum input 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have truble setting input width to 100% in my search form. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Tried setting 100% everywhere posible, put it's only changes when I set size px.

http://jsfiddle.net/26Gmz/

```
.searchInput {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}


.searchIn {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    outline-width: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    width: 97%;
}

                <form method="post">
                        <div class="searchEn">
                                <input type=hidden name="do" value=search>
                                <input type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search" />
                                <div class="searchInput">
                                        <input class="searchIn" name="story" width="100%" type="text" />
                                </div>

                        </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Is the class of the upmost parent div class="SearchEn" supposed to be class="searchIn"? Or is this intentional?

Comment: Table is always problematic, because the table rendering of the browsers manipulates hardly, and randomly overrides your settings. If you can avoid them, it is better if you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the effect you are after by changing the `display` rule of `.searchInput` to `block` (and then the `width` to `98%`) like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26Gmz/3/))

```
.searchInput {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 98%;
}
```

Or for a more complete fix (addressing a bunch of padding and width issues) you could use this CSS ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26Gmz/6/)) (changes are commented)

```
.searchEn {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0px, #DFDFDF 100%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    /*Push the right side over slightly more*/
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 4px;
}
.searchInput {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 29px;
    /*Remove padding from this element (now in the parent element)*/
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*These can be full width if you fix the padding on the parent element*/
    width: 100%;
}
.searchIn {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    outline-width: 0;
    padding-left: 4px;
    /*Center the input box better inside the container*/
    padding-top: 6px;
    /*And make the input full width*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` could be helpful to keep the width consistent at 100%.